# PHP Laravel (->with) only 1 result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models: `TheSeries` and `TheEpisodes`.

`TheSeries` has many `TheEpisodes` and `TheEpisodes` has one `TheSeries`.

I am trying to list all `TheSeries` and display latestEpisode in each, by using `TheEpisodes.addDate`.

The code I have right now is this:

```
$TheSeries = TheSeries::with('TheEpisodes');
```

What should I do to display only latest 1 episode for each TV serial?

## EDIT

`->take(1)` and `->limit(1)` do not work for `TheEpisodes`

### EDIT (Latest Semi-Working Code)

```
$results = TheSeries::take(5)->with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('addDate', 'desc');
}])->get()
```

This works, it returns the episodes in correct order but I am unable to limit the results to 1. This following codes don't work:

```
// Example 1
$results = TheSeries::take(5)->with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('addDate', 'desc')->take(1);
}])->get()
// Example 2
$results = TheSeries::take(5)->with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('addDate', 'desc')->limit(1);
}])->get()
// Example 3
$results = TheSeries::take(5)->with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('addDate', 'desc')->first();
}])->get()
```

Those are the column names of the tables:

TheSeries - id, originalTitle, aliasTitle, description, imageURL, startingDate, endingDate, activeBool

TheEpisodes: id, seriesID, authorID, addDate, episodeVersion

Comment: It is not and easy task take a look here: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: @Froxz so this is impossible? I am obliged to display all entries?

Comment: it seems so, but the thing is you can return all child row, and you will a collection, laravel gives a good tool to work with collections, you can try filtering this collection DOC:https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections But you can always use `DB` not eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `TheLatestEpisode` `hasOne` relation on your `TheSeries` model:

```
class TheSeries extends Model
{
    public function TheLatestEpisode()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TheEpisode::class, 'seriesID')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Then you can easily do:

```
$series = TheSeries::with('TheLatestEpisode')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as:

```
$TheSeries = TheSeries::with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1);
}])
->get();
```

Or try with `limit` as:

```
$TheSeries = TheSeries::with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
}])
->get();
```

Comment: This returns empty `TheEpisodes`

Comment: Does this `TheSeries::with('TheEpisodes')->get()` returns all `TheEpisodes`?

Comment: If I remove ->take(1) returns in good order, but I need only 1.

Comment: yes, it does, ->take(1) does not work well in this case.

Comment: Then please try with `->limit(1)`.

Comment: Same thing "the_episodes": []

Comment: Can you show your `TheEpisodes` relation in your question?

Comment: `take(1)` should work. I've just tested and it works perfectly with my data in 5.3 project.

Answer (score 0):

```
$TheSeries = TheSeries::with(['TheEpisodes' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
}])
->get();
```

can't work?

Comment: This does work, but only for one `TheSeries`, the other one is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `DB` statement ?

```
DB::table('TheEpisodes')
->leftjoin('TheSeries','TheEpisodes.SeriesId','=','TheSeries.id')
->select('TheEpisodes.*','TheSeries.id as sId','TheSeries.name as sName',...)
->orderBy('TheEpisodes. addDate','desc')
->take(1)
->get();
```

Comment: I am trying to use Laravel feauteres to keep my code clean.

Comment: Sounds good and I'd do the same but also I'd try other methods at least to check that I am on the right way )

Comment: it works fine if I dont use ->take(1), but there is an issue with ->take(1)

Comment: even `->limit(1)` @PHPLover ?

Comment: Yep, same issue. @Nour, can I demonstrate you the issue by screen sharing software like Team Viewer? You would be able to see even the database structure.

Comment: What do you get without any limitations  ?

Comment: Like 100-200 episodes :D

Comment: I am unable to limit them to 1 inside :(

Comment: I'd like to help you, could you share the columns names of both tables ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131729/discussion-between-php-lover-and-nour).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your TheSeries model: (it is easier)

```
public function getLatestEpisodeAttribute(){
    $episode = TheEpisodes::where('series_id',$this->attributes['id'])
            ->latest()
            ->first();
    if(!$episode){
        return "no episodes for this Series";
    }
    return $episode;
}
```

On your controller just do the query normally without including anything related to `TheSeries` and you can access it values in your blade file like this:

```
//lets suppose there is a title attibute in the episodes
{{$TheSeries->latest_episode->title}}
//or a duration attribute
{{$TheSeries->latest_episode->duration}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found, was to create a one-to-one relationship with orderBy('addDate'), it works!!!

Reference: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Answer (score -2):

```
$TheSeries = TheSeries::with('TheEpisodes')->first();
```

Or

```
$TheSeries = TheSeries::with('TheEpisodes')->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: This will take only 1 `TheSeries`, I need only 1 `TheEpisode`

Comment: This example will only take 1 TV serial not 1 Episode.